# Framesize issue while minimising and maximising java swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, layout-manager

I have set the frame size of my java swing application to:
    frame.setSize(700, 500);

Whenever I maximise the window, I want the UI Elements to adjust and take the full application size.
Right now when I maximise, the frame occupying the full window remains blank, UI elements remain at same position as before.
HOw should I change the code so that whenever I maximise the window, the UI Elements should occupy the window ?

Comment: Change the layout manager you are using to something that wants to fill the space...

Comment: I was reading and got looks like BorderLayout may help. I will try and post the answer here. THanks for suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just a sample code you can you this for your app, for `GridBagConstraint` to work for re size you need to set `weightx` or `weighty` property to non zero.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class app extends JFrame{
  public app(String title){
    super(title);

    GridBagLayout layout = new GridBagLayout();
    GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
    getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
    constraints.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("First Name:");
    constraints.gridx = 0;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.gridwidth = 1;
    constraints.gridheight = 1;
    constraints.weightx = 0;
    constraints.weighty = 0;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);    
    layout.setConstraints(l1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(l1);

    //JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(); //removed passing column size.
    constraints.gridx = 1;
    constraints.gridy = 0;
    constraints.weightx = 1;
    constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
    constraints.insets = new Insets(5,5,5,5);
    layout.setConstraints(t1, constraints);
    getContentPane().add(t1);


    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(700,500);
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){
    new app("App").setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: you breaking getPreferredSize came from JTextField(10); and calculated in GBC by using setSize(700,500);

Comment: put there JPanel and to override getPreferredSize with Dimansion (700, 500) minus Borders added by Native OS